# Different ID how will call on same method in android

Tags: java, android, xml

## This is my XML code

```
   <ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.dk.azenna.Document">

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="500px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/issue"
            android:layout_width="500px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:hint="Issue Date"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/expiry"
            android:layout_width="500px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/issue"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:hint="Expiry Date"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>          

     </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

when you press this Two EditText(issue date and Expiry Date). I want to show datepicker.

This above code are properly working for single EditText(issue date).how to implement for both EditText??

## This is my Main Activity.Java code

```
  public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    EditText txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.issue );
    txtDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus){
            if(hasfocus){
                DateDialog dialog=new DateDialog(view);
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

### This is my DateDialog.java Code

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
 public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
EditText txtdate;
public DateDialog(View view){
    txtdate=(EditText)view;
}
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);


}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    String date=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
    txtdate.setText(date);
}    
}
```

Comment: you want two different dataPicklers or one dataPicker connected to two editTexts?

Comment: i want two date pickers(Ex:From date to TO date).now one date picker is working(From Date). i also want ToDate date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make two instances of you `edittext` and sign listeners to them.

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
//first edittext
    EditText txtDate =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.issue);
    txtDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus){
            if(hasfocus){
                DateDialog dialog=new DateDialog(view);
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

            }
        }
    });
//second edittext
    EditText txtDate2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.expiry);
    txtDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus){
            if(hasfocus){
                DateDialog dialog=new DateDialog(view);
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

            }
        }
    });
}
```